# Is that possible to insert a poll / survey in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Is it possible to insert a survey/pull request into a normal Stack Overflow question/answer website or is there a specific place to do that?

If it is possible, I want to built a survey to understand what are the people's opinion about the preferred **number formatting** worldwide.

It would be my pleasure to achieve this by publishing a poll/survey in Stack Overflow (if possible) where everyone can "check" their favorite answers and discuss about motivations and different points of view.
It would be equally good even if there were the possibility to just publish a link to the page containing the survey.

Comment: Polls are explicitly offtopic everywhere on Stack Exchange. I have voted to move this question to [Meta] because it formally belongs there, but if it makes it through the migration it will probably be closed anyway.

Comment: @GSerg  It's Ok I understand: and I also suppose it is not even possible to publish a link to a page that offers a survey. Good to know. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @GSerg Just out of curiosity, where is that made explicit? A google search didn't turn up anything.

Comment: @jforberg This info is mentioned in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, and nowhere on Stack Exchange would a poll be on topic.

If your question needs a poll, then your question is off topic on Stack Overflow and everywhere else on Stack Exchange.

Any situation where you would need a poll would mean that there is no definitive or "right" answer, and polls would be primarily opinion/experience based. That would mean that the question would be closed as "Primarily Opinion Based" anyways.

Comment: Ok I will not publish any survey. But IMHO it would be interesting to have a section where to do such things.

Answer (score 4):

On any question click:

`flag|should be closed|primarily opinion based`

You will see:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert
>   experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost
>   entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific
>   expertise.

So... No. A poll is always about opinions, and opinion based questions are offtopic.

Comment: I don't mean to seem polemic but even opinions are based on experience. And viceversa. Every one, even here on Stack Exchange network, answers to question on the basis of his own expertise and experience (knohow): it's like opinion. I'm pretty sure that everybody that expresses an opinion bases it on its own (or others) previous experiences and opinions. This because experiences isn't only ours but of the whole community which every one learn from.

Comment: But of course I'm still a newbie so maybe there are some points about this topic that still are a dark matter, that in the future will allow me to better understand differences between the two things.  But at the moment I still have difficulties to track a sharp line between the two things cause I still see them as strictly related. Any way I will respect the rules.

Comment: Unfortunately, when it comes to opinion based questions, newbies act as pros. You can't decide who is pro and who's not.

Comment: Right: this is because it has to be clear that is just a poll and a poll is opinion based. Nevertheless every one can upvote or downvote every answer and every comment here... everyone that votes, does it if opinions of the answerer and the voter match. So even voting an answer is "some kind" of opinion based choice... For example I expressed the idea to propose a poll but i received n down votes... every voter expressed a respectable opinion about... Opinions are everywhere: impossible to stop them. It is just possible to study them: this topic is the proof, in fact is opinion based.

Comment: Also without a section dedicated to opinions what is the teaching that we are giving to new generations people? That opinions are sameway wrong? That opinions are some way illegal? That opinion are someway to be rejected? This is the kind of message that passes cause this limitation. Sorry, but I think this is a wrong message, a wrong teaching. Remember what Voltaire said once: "I do not think like you, but I would give my life to make you say what you think". IMHO this is the spirit that this world really needs nowadays. If not history really doesn't teach nothing.

Comment: Nevertheless I understand the need to separate opinions from technical informations.